# C# WASM without Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, webassembly

I want to be able to call C# code from JavaScript. The mono project used to have a WASM SDK that you could download from their old Jenkins server, but that is no longer public. Existing docs tend to point toward those builds. The Azure Devops builds do not include this SDK. A few messages I've seen on their Github account indicate that they are now focusing on the .NET 6 for WASM. I do not wish to use the Blazor components. Is there a way in .NET 6 to build a minimally sized WASM binary without the Blazor UI?

Comment: The Mono WASM SDK became Blazor. `I do not wish to use the Blazor components.` why?

Comment: The UI components. I just want to compile C# and call it from JavaScript and vice versa.

Comment: "why?" Is that a serious question?

Comment: Unfortunately, probably is. A lot of people don't believe in framework diversity, even if there are plenty of legitimate reasons for it.

Comment: Blazor is a tool meant to replace JS with C#. Web Assembly is meant to run along side of JS, not replace it. Blazor would not be to C# and Web Assembly to what Emscripten is to C/C++ and Web Assembly. 

Also, Blazor advertises to write UI Components in C#. Google engineers state to not write your components in Web Assembly.

Comment: I'd love to be able to write something like a sass compiler or typescript compiler in webassembly (ideally something performant like C#).  yarn/npm is a great way to distribute command line tools, especially for the node ecosystem.

Comment: @dman I agree with this, especially "Google engineers state to not write your components in Web Assembly." Blazor's biggest flaw is doing WAY too much performance-sensitive stuff, most notably DOM building and diffing, in the C# world then transferring it all over to JS through very inefficient interop. Thus Blazor apps with any significant complexity are not really usable, even after AOT. Building your UI natively and calling into C# as needed is currently the only viable approach if you expect people to actually use and pay for your app. Unfortunately MS doesn't officially support this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos here's my question about why I don't wish to use Blazor https://stackoverflow.com/q/70474778/810328

Comment: @vcRobe that doesn't explain the `why`. Quite often that's the **most** important question. When I asked `why` I had Electron apps in mind. Or maybe someone wanted to create Web components. Or just a transpiler that generates WASM from C# source.  If there are 100 ways to do something, or 100 things to do with one thing, you really need to know what the actual problem is to be able to pick a solution or narrow down the options.

Comment: They just moved Mono WASM, it's not gone and has been "killed". I see people pushing to the repo regularly, as recent as a few hours ago, so it's definitely still around

Comment: @AaronCarter it seemed to be dead for a bit, with no documentation of where it was moved and Microsoft indicating that all development efforts were to be focused on Blazor. It seems since I asked this question that they have changed their minds.

Comment: @eltiare totally understandable and I was just updating info, not criticizing you. I was just lucky to have stumbled upon that information as to its whereabouts and status and hoped it would be helpful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes it's absolutely possible. Blazor does not have a monopoly on C#/WASM and it's far from clear that it's going to wind up being the best long term option (and a lot of evidence it's not).

I recommend starting with the Uno WASM Bootstrap. https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap

2022-06-30 Edit -
More evidence Blazor is not the only game in town nor even at the forefront of innovation here:
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/06/29/uno-platform-4-4.aspx

Comment: I was really hoping that .NET 6 would just support this. But it looks like a good lead. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah Microsoft doesn't seem to be interested in WASM except in the context of Blazor. Very strange and annoying that they killed the Mono SDK. Plus, despite a huge outpouring of support for a WASM/Web target for MAUI, they've stayed completely silent on it. It really is inexplicable. But the guy behind Uno is super smart and helpful and really believes in combining C#+WASM so he is very open to projects like this that don't use Blazor OR Uno. Follow his directions to the letter and you will be able to get it working I'm sure.

Comment: FYI, using the Uno Bootstrapper, I actually ported a huge portion of WPF to WASM. Unfortunately the performance wasn't acceptable, but it was a fun project. Point is there is a huge potential world out there for this beyond Blazor.

Comment: @PeterMoore I'd love to see that fork. I've been wondering if it was possible to port WPF to WASM myself. I was thinking that once AOT and WebGPU was implemented, we could port DXVK using Emscripten to WASM to replicated the DX GPU functionality.

Comment: @PeterMoore "Microsoft doesn't seem to be interested in WASM except in the context of Blazor" I don't think this is true.  Check out Microsoft's work with Krustlet: https://krustlet.dev/, WAGI: https://github.com/deislabs/wagi, and Hippo: https://github.com/deislabs/hippo.  Looking at that body of work, MSFT has a very different context for WASM.

Comment: @CharlesChen All of those projects seem oriented around wasm used as servers/microservices, not wasm for in-browser js use.

Comment: @MikeAsdf absolutely right. I didn't want to shoot down the suggestions but it remains true that Microsoft's only investment in WASM from an application development perspective is Blazor. And basically killing the Mono WASM SDK really was a big and unnecessary blow to anyone looking for an alternative.

Comment: What about https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/dotnet-wasi-sdk?

Comment: Not familiar with WASI but with .NET 7 they have taken significant steps toward decoupling.NET WASM from Blazor, which I think is great. Excited to see what evolves from it.

Comment: I want to point out that the great thing about Uno.Bootsrap.Wasm is it is independent of the Uno Platform.  If you don't want to learn a new UI framework like Uno or Blazor, then Uno.Bootstrap.Wasm lets you compile and load a client side .NET WebAssembly in a traditional website/browser context.  I've used it to build things like WASM JQuery wrapper so I can take a traditional ASP.NET MVC site and implement the client side UI logic in C# instead of Javascript.

Comment: @AaronLS do you know if they finally got Visual Studio debugging working with Uno.Bootstrap? That was the one drawback that stopped me from actually using it but it's been a few years since I checked. (Instead I use "Blazor" but bypass all the UI stuff.)

Comment: @EmperorEto Just spent couple hours getting it to work.  The Uno Bootstrap documentation seems like it falls behind the Uno Platform documentation.  I needed to add an inspectUri to launchsettings.json for it to work.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that dotnet 7 has improved WASM support. More information is provided in https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-wasm/

Answer (score 5):

NativeAOT-LLVM, an experimental c# compiler not official supported by Microsoft, (https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM) can also compile C# to Wasm without any UI framework requirements.  There's a similar question about libraries at [Compiling C# project to WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474778/compiling-c-sharp-project-to-webassembly)

Comment: an example of NativeAOT-LLVM WebAssembly, thanks to @S Waye
https://github.com/zwcloud/MinimalCSharpWasmWebGL-NativeAOT-LLVM

Comment: a simpler example: https://github.com/zwcloud/CSharpWasmSamples

Answer (score 5):

The Mono WASM SDK is continued in the dotnet/runtime repo. The tooling based on old **Packager.exe** has evolved into a MSBuild/csproj based solution:

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/mono/wasm

samples:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/mono/sample/wasm

The key issue when I trying to use code in a custom project (not within the sample) is that we need to reference a private assembly `System.Private.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll` which is included in [Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.browser-wasm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.browser-wasm). The code is almost the same as `WebAssembly.Bindings.dll` in old mono wasm sdk.

Here is a screenshot of a WebGL page I created, based on dotnet/runtime/mono/wasm:
[image]

BTW there is a viewpoint that the performance of implementing WebGL via calling JavaScript functions from C#, is bad: https://marcoscobena.com/?i=wave-engine-web-performance

Comment: Nice find. DOM manipulation in WASM is going to be slow for the foreseeable future but plans are in the works to bring it up to par with JavaScript.