# Compiling C# project to WebAssembly

Tags: c#, webassembly, .net-6.0

I need to compile a C# project to WebAssembly and be able to call some methods from JavaScript.

I want to use it in an old ASP.NET MVC 4 application that needs to add some new features and I prefer to use C# instead JavaScript/TypeScript.

Ideally I would like to compile to WebAssembly using .Net 6 but I can use any other alternative.

I'm running .Net 6 on Windows 10 Version 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1415)

I've installed:

- Visual Studio 2022
- the workload "wasm-tools" (.NET WebAssembly build tools)

But every time I search for a tutorial, example, etc, about how to use the .NET WebAssembly build tools the results are about Blazor.

I've read [this tutorial](https://itnext.io/run-c-natively-in-the-browser-through-the-web-assembly-via-mono-wasm-60f3d55dd05a?gi=9ab60a74b5bb) but I can't find the mono-wasm compiler (and like I said above I would like to use .Net 6 to compile whenever possible.)

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

There is the experimental NativeAOT-LLVM (https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM).  It is not an official Microsoft WebAssembly compiler, its supported by the community, but .Net 6 is available.  First, and this only works on Windows, you need to install and activate emscripten.  I wont cover installing emscripten here, but you can read https://emscripten.org/docs/getting_started/downloads.html.

To create and run a dotnet c# library:

1. Create the library project:

```
dotnet new classlib
```

2. Create the library code, we'll use something simple that avoids any problems marshalling things like javascript strings, so in the `Class1.cs` file add

```cs
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedCallersOnly(EntryPoint = "Answer")]
public static int Answer()
{
    return 41;
}
```

This will create a function, `Answer` that can be called from outside managed code, i.e. from Javascript

3. Add a nuget.config

```
dotnet new nugetconfig
```

4. In the nuget.config add the reference to allow the experimental package to be downloaded.  You can also change the package download location to avoid it adding experimental packages to your global nuget location. Your `nuget.config` should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value=".packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <!--To inherit the global NuGet package sources remove the <clear/> line below -->
    <clear />
    <add key="dotnet-experimental" value="https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-experimental/nuget/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

5. Add the package references for the compiler to your project's `csproj` file so that it ends with this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler.LLVM" Version="7.0.0-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="runtime.win-x64.Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler.LLVM" Version="7.0.0-*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

6. Publish your project to wasm:

```
dotnet publish /p:NativeLib=Static /p:SelfContained=true -r browser-wasm -c Debug /p:TargetArchitecture=wasm /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver=false /p:EmccExtraArgs="-s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=_Answer%2C_NativeAOT_StaticInitialization -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=cwrap" --self-contained
```

This will build the project referencing the browser-wasm runtime.  `MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver` stops the build process checking for Mono's wasm-tools Visual Studio workload which we are not using here. (Mono is a different compiler and runtime, which I believe is getting similar support for .net 7).  `EmccExtraArgs` allows us to add parameters to emscripten's `emcc` and we need that to export the two function we will call from Javascript: `Answer` - this is our library function, and `NativeAOT_StaticInitialization` this is called once per lifetime of the wasm module to initialize the runtime.  Note the additional underscores in front of the names.  The compilation takes a while, but when finished you should have a subfolder `bin\x64\Debug\net6.0\browser-wasm\native` where you will find the wasm, some html, and some javascript.  In the html file at the end, before the closing `body` tag, initialize the runtime and call your function with:

```
<script>
    Module.onRuntimeInitialized = _ => {
    const corertInit = Module.cwrap('NativeAOT_StaticInitialization', 'number', []);
    corertInit();

    const answer = Module.cwrap('Answer', 'number', []);
    console.log(answer());
    };
</script>
```

Then server that up with the web server of your choosing, browse to the page and check the console where if everything has gone to plan, and the stars align (this is experimental), you should see
[image]

Comment: They have a instruction markdown on how to do this now:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/blob/ce43f371e1761fe6335f8c63d344e605b892ebe9/docs/using-nativeaot/compiling.md#webassembly

Comment: 18 MB WASM file being generated for same code above returning integer. Seems like it is because of other functions being exported, does anyone know?

Comment: There's a few things that contribute to the size.  1) this is a debug build so includes debug information and the Wasm is not optimized.  Note that the LLVM backend for RyuJIT used in the NativeAOT-LLVM project does not support the release mode of RyuJIT which would also reduce the size.   2) Reflection meta data is included to support reflection.  You can remove that with reflection free mode. 3) The required parts of the dotnet runtime are included - there is a "zerosharp" way to get a tiny wasm file, but there is no runtime that way.

Comment: thanks, i am pure JS guy and new to C# and web assembly world. Any link you can suggest to get better understanding of what you mentioned above?

Comment: 1. For the debug information, this is DWARF - it includes information about the source lines for each wasm instruction (can also include information about variables and types but that is very limited in NativeAOT-LLVM). 2) Reflection free mode - https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/coreclr/nativeaot/docs/reflection-free-mode.md.  3) zerosharp: https://github.com/MichalStrehovsky/zerosharp

Comment: Does this work with windows forms?

Comment: @CalebLiu, no it does not.

Comment: @SWaye how did you find out that using `UnmanagedCallersOnly` will allow wasm output to expose the annotated function? This particular use case, i.e. exporting a library to wasm is almost something that Microsoft does not want to document. I've been looking at the documentation and it's always about running some exe or even asp.net core itself in the browser, as if that has any real life value. Is there some documentation out there that would help people who are interested in what is asked in this question: C# libraries as webassembly? How did you find out about `UnmanagedCallersOnly` ?

Comment: @GrumpyRodriguez I contribute to the NativeAOT-LLVM project and there is some documentation there https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/blob/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM/docs/using-nativeaot/compiling.md#webassembly-native-libraries:

Comment: @SWaye That's brilliant. I did not see that piece of documentation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across : https://github.com/Elringus/DotNetJS

Looks very interesting and closer to how I would want to use c# in the web browser. I will be looking at this in the next few months

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap for awhile as a straightforward way to compile a C# assembly to a WASM package.  You add the nuget package to a console project and make a couple minor changes:
https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap/blob/main/doc/using-the-bootstrapper.md

This is separate from the larger Uno Platform and can be used without using their UI platform. It is just the tooling needed to compile your assembly to a simple WASM package and the JavaScript needed to load it (or "bootstrap" it) into the browser. The nice thing is because they leverage this on the mature Uno platform, the tooling has been exercised pretty thoroughly.

It produces a folder containing the WASM assembly and all the JavaScript/etc. static files that do the work to retrieve and load the WASM assembly.  So all the code in your console app runs client side in the browser.  The area is still evolving and there's a few different ways to call JavaScript from C# and vice versa.  My jQuery WASM wrapper uses alot of `WebAssemblyRuntime.InvokeJS(@$` to call JavaScript and ultimately interact with the DOM, but depending what you are trying to accomplish there are easier ways to do this in .NET 7 using import and export attributes and n C# methods to expose them to JavaScript.

I use MSBUILD tasks to copy the WASM distribution folder into my MVC project to be served as additional static files.      Alternatively you would just host the static files as a separate static site. Then reference them from my layout.cshtml, the same way you'd reference a JavaScript file.

They also document an Embedded Mode that packages it slightly differently to simplify loading the WASM package in some scenarios. I have not tested this yet since it's newer, but seems like it may be more appropriate where it's being integrated into an existing site.

Alot of the use cases for WASM seem to be SPA's but like you I just wanted to use it as client side logic for my traditional MVC web app, instead of JavaScript. At some levels you usually need to generate or call JavaScript to interop with the DOM.

There are now some WASM libraries out there using this technology that act as C# wrappers for things like jQuery so that you can skip past dealing with the JavaScript interop layer and work in C# to access and manipulate the DOM/HTML. Of course the JS interop layer is still there, but the wrapper is already built out so you don't have to write any JS.