# Generating Webassembly from pure C# class

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I'm making my backend on C# and frontend on JS.
I want to reuse some alghoritms written in C# in browser JavaScript.
Simplified example:

```
    class Fibonacci {
        int Fib(int x) {
            if (x == 0) return 0;
            int prev = 0;
            int next = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
            {
                int sum = prev + next;
                prev = next;
                next = sum;
            }
           return next;
    }
```

Is it possible to compile one library-independent class to `WebAssembly` and use it from browser? How?

Comment: I would start reading this => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly

Comment: Wouldn't that more or less be a straight paste into being JavaScript? Or is this a contrived example?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, it is contrived example. I have more complex algorithm, that I want to keep up to date with my backend.

Comment: If it's Blazor WAsm, why generate the wasm yourself? Just write it in C# and let translating it be Blazor's problem? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the requirement..

Comment: I'm writing my frontend on js/ts stack. I clarified the question

Comment: The latest .net 6 framework does support [AOT for Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ahead-of-time-aot-compilation). It requires some tooling setup, and you will have to separate that from the Blazor stuff. I don't think you can avoid adding the runtime.

Comment: Related: https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/WebIDL-Binder.html#webidl-binder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with NativeAOT-LLVM (https://github.com/dotnet/runtimelab/tree/feature/NativeAOT-LLVM).  There's a similar question with a full answer at [Compiling C# project to WebAssembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474778/compiling-c-sharp-project-to-webassembly)

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, C# needs some middleware / framework to convert it to wasm. If your use case does not warrant Blazor, you might try the UNO platform:  https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Wasm.Bootstrap

Comment: Can't it compile to pure wasm withput additional runtime?

Comment: You can refer to these for more clarification: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#ahead-of-time-aot-compilation https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44316

Answer (score -5):

You can call .NET methods form JavaScript functions like this

Here is the razor html

```
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<button @onclick=@CallToJS >Call JS function</button>
```

Here is the code behind

```
 @code {
    /// <summary>
    /// This method calls javascript function with .net object reference parameter
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Awaitable task</returns>
    private async Task CallToJS() => await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("sayHi", DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is called from javascript
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">some string parameter coming from javascript</param>
    /// <returns>Returns string</returns>
    [JSInvokable] 
    public async Task<string> CalledFromJS(string name)
    {
        //  Here you can call your class library
        return $"Hi {name}";
    }
}
```

And this is the JavaScript code calling .NET method

```
function sayHi(dotNetHelper) {
    var promise = dotNetHelper.invokeMethodAsync('CalledFromJS', "Surinder");

    promise.then(function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    });    
}
```

Comment: IJSRuntime requires the Blazor framework - something the asker does not want.

Comment: Blazor has a clear cut system to call JavaScript functions from .NET code and call .NET functions form JavaScript. I am sorry to say that some times development experience from JavaScript libraries try to implement things the way developers are used to or feel comfortable with. I would say its as important to unlearn somethings as its important to learn new things. So try to understand the intention behind creation of Blazor framework and reap the benefits of it. Its my personal opinion, no intention to hurt anyone.